# collectd not sharing information to graphite for all data

Tags: graphite, collectd

I have a strange one.

A number of data items are being collected by collectd and appear correctly with
collectdctl -s /var/run/collectdctl listval|getval and so forth.

These are then rendered into graphite effectively for most items.

Recently, the collectd-graphite connection ceased to be operational
for several recently added items. While it appears in collectd and
is queryable via collectdctl, it remains not on the graphite page.

I am asking to find out how you would approach this.

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: I know this is old, but i solved a similiar problem with setting the *MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE = inf*

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a number of ways you can troubleshoot this, but I end up almost always resorting to tcpdump, sigh. First enable debug logging in collectd just to make sure it really doesn't spit out an error message (LogLevel "debug" https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:LogFile although often collectd is compiled with debug logging disabled).

Then run tcpdump on the graphite server using the `-s0 -X` flags to tcpdump so you get the packet contents. (You can also use a more sophisticated network sniffer that prints the tcp data stream.) Check whether you see the data items that are missing the packets and whether they look appropriate (see https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Write_Graphite). Typically this step allows me to quickly determine whether the problem is the sending collectd or the receiving service.